# Selecting primary keys that do not have foreign keys in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, one-to-many

For simplification, I have two tables related with one to many using a foreign key, for example:

```
Users table:
id
name

Actions table:
id
user_id
```

one user may have many actions or not. I need an sql select that returns users ids that don't have a user_id value in the actions table.

```
Users Table:
id      name
1       John
2       Smith
3       Alice

Actions Table:
id      user_id
1       3
2       1
```

So I need an sql query that returns the user id 2 (Smith) because the foreign key values don't include the id 2

I tried the following SQL, but it returns all users ids:

```
SELECT users.id from users left join actions on actions.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

```
select u.id
from users u
left outer join actions a on a.user_id = u.id
where a.user_id is null
```

Answer (score 3):

Optimized version would be:

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN actions a
ON a.user_id = u.id
AND ISNULL(a.user_id)
```

Comment: you are right i had a miss type correct is: ON a.user_id = u.id

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT u.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN actions a
   ON a.user_id = u.id
WHERE a.user_id IS NULL
```

Comment: Yeah, had a typo in my query.