# Select primary keys that do not have foreign keys or not have enough foreign keys

Tags: sql, sqlite, join

I'd like to get all the charge id that doesn't have a foreign key or not have enough number as confirmation_to_supply

For example,

```
Charge Table:
 id
 confirmation_to_supply

Pay Table:
 id
 charge_id
```

Lets put some value

```
Charge Table:
 id: 1  confirmation_to_supply: 1
 id: 2  confirmation_to_supply: 2
 id: 3  confirmation_to_supply: 3

Pay Table:
 id: 1 charge_id: 2
 id: 2 charge_id: 2
 id: 3 charge_id: 3
```

Result should by

```
charge_id
-----------
    1
    3
```

So 1 should appear because there is no such a foreign key in pay table
And 3 should appear because there is not enough foreign key as confirmation_to_supply in charge table.

My question is very similar to this one: [Selecting primary keys that do not have foreign keys in another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13108587/selecting-primary-keys-that-do-not-have-foreign-keys-in-another-table][1])

```
 select char.id
 from Charge AS char
 left outer join Pay AS p on p.charge_id = char.id
 where p.charge_id is null
```

This query give only the null

```
  charge_id
-----------
    1
```

I need to get also the id 3.

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with a `group` by and `having` clause:

```
select char.id
from Charge AS char
left outer join Pay AS p on p.charge_id = char.id
group by char.id, char.confirmation_to_supply
having count(p.charge_id) < confirmation_to_supply
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your fast answer!

Answer (score 0):

What if you added an OR to the WHERE statement that shows the keys where the number of foreign keys is less than 2.

```
select char.id
 from Charge AS char
 left outer join Pay AS p on p.charge_id = char.id
 where p.charge_id is null OR (SELECT COUNT(p.charge_id) FROM Pay) < 2
```